# TAPI App on 64bits OS

Tags: 64-bit, tapi

I have a TAPI Application (Delphi 2007) working on 32bits OSs (XP, Vista, Win7). The TAPI server is 32bits Windows 2003 SP2.

While TAPI APP is running on 64bits OS, I can connect to the line but i cannot get TAPI messages on my App.

I can see messages have arrived on machine through Tracing tapisrv but the WaitForSingleObjectEx to the event handle (returned by lineInitializeEx) is never signaled (always returns WAIT_TIMEOUT).

I've also tried C++ code and 64bits compiler but the 64bits App had the same behavior (except not even starting on 32bits OS :-) ).

Is there any ideas how i can receive the TAPI messages to my App???

EDIT: Well, it seems that only the messages regarding incoming calls are cut. If (while App is running) i execute "tcmsetup /c /d" (=disable TAPI) then i DO receive LINE_CLOSE and LINE_REMOVE messages. Then, if i execute "tcmsetup /c server_name", i DO get the LINE_CREATE message. I can lineOpen the new line provided but still CANNOT get LINE_APPNEWCALL, LINE_CALLSTATE etc

Comment: Does it have to be a 64-bit application?

Comment: U mean??? I built with delphi (no 64bit compiler yet) and wasn't playing on 64bit OS. I tried test code on VS2005, and built to 32 and 64 bit. Neither works on 64bit OS. Connects to line but cannot receive messages. WaitForSingleObjectEx still no signal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a Microsoft bug, after all. For more details and a HotFix, check http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2304914.

Answer (score 0):

What underlying TSP, e.g. cisco.tsp, is your TAPI application connecting to?

Edit: I googled regarding a configuration such as yours and noted this [article](http://www.ms-news.net/f3612/32-bit-tapisrv-64-bit-remotesp-32-bit-tapiclient-gets-noincoming-calls-5809024.html) about a similar issue to the problem you're describing. It seems there is a problem regarding impersonating a user when the remotesp.tsp is involved.

Comment: I'm using system's "remotesp.tsp" to connect to TAPI server. The server is using "Panasonic KX-TDA Version 3.0.0.4" (ctsp0000.tsp) to connect to PBX (through USB cable)